# Unable to use json parsed object in another call in jmeter?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am using jsr223 assertion with groovy script ,I am saving the parsed response as variable

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();
def t1= prev.getResponseDataAsString();

def response = slurper.parseText(t1);
vars.putObject("Summary", response);
```

Now I want to use this Summary variable in another call, so that I can assert it

```
def nn = ${SummaryJDBC};
```

But I am getting this error

> jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler
>   'Competitive_Landscape(Past_awardees)' : java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Please show the `raw response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) method:

```
 nn = vars.getObject("SummaryJDBC")
```